# react async props to component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've got an issue with async props that I am passing to a component.

The props are from an state manager that gets them with an API call

```
      const productState = useAppSelector((state) => state.product);
      const categoriesState = useAppSelector((state) => state.categories);
```

Then I pass them to the component which is rendered only when the props are loaded.

```
     <AsyncWrapperComponent
              isLoading={productState.isLoading && categoriesState.isLoading}
            >
              <AvailableItemView
                productList={productState.products}
                categoriesList={menuCategoryMock}
              />
            </AsyncWrapperComponent>
```

problem is that the props don't wait then the component renders with empty props.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!productState.isLoading && !categoriesState.isLoading) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [productState.isLoading, categoriesState.isLoading]);
```

This will trigger a re-render when either values of productState.isLoading or categoriesState.isLoading changes.

```
<AsyncWrapperComponent isLoading={isLoading}>
   // same as yours
</AsyncWrapperComponent>
```